# Why can't I pipe into cd?

Tags: bash

Why can't I pipe stuff into cd?

Example:

```
$ pwd >> ~/mloc
$ cd /
$ tail -n 1 ~/mloc | cd
```

cd fails. If do: `cd $(tail -n 1 ~/mloc)`, it works.

I understand the last command I wrote works, but I don't understand why I can't pipe into cd.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Piping to a process sends data to it in place of what you'd type *after* you have launched the process, *not* what you'd type as part of the command that launches the process.

(`cd` is also not a process but that's less important, I address it below.)

*Piping* attaches one command's *output* to another command's *input*. Consider:

```bsh
foo | bar
```

That runs `bar`, runs `foo`, and:

- instead of showing `foo`'s output on the terminal, it directs it to `bar` as input.
- instead of *taking* input to `bar` *from the terminal*, it takes it from `foo`'s output.

(Both those bullet points actually express the same thing.)

So, what happens when you run `tail -n 1 ~/mloc | cd`?

- It runs `cd` and, whenever `cd` accepts input while running, it takes that input from the output of `tail -n 1 ~/mloc`.
- `cd` *never* accepts input while running.

See [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) (Wikipedia) for more information on the precise meaning of *input* and *output* in this answer. (Here, by input, I mean "standard input" and by output I mean "standard output.")

There is also the issue that `cd` is not actually a program, but a shell builtin, so when you run `cd` no new process is launched. But that is not *really* why what you're trying doesn't work, because:

- Using pipes to pass command line arguments, as you've been attempting, will not ever work for any program.
- There's no reason a shell couldn't be written to accommodate pipes *to* a shell builtin, considering that they accommodate pipes *from* shell builtins.

  Note that sometimes when you use a shell builtin like it's a real program, what happens is that the real program of the same name is run instead. But there's no separate program for `cd`, and we can pipe *from* `cd`; for example, run `cd blah 2>&1 | less`; if `blah` doesn't exist or isn't a directory, you'll be able to view the error in `less`.

Finally, consider what's different about `cd $(tail -n 1 ~/mloc)`. This command:

- Runs `tail -n 1 ~/mloc` and captures its output.
- Instead of displaying the output, constructs a command consisting of it appended to `cd` .
- Runs that command.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: cd doesn't work like that.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-cd

The longer answer is that in bash, commands in a pipeline are each executed in a subshell. Since cd is a shell builtin, it only affects the shell it's executed in. If you cd within a subshell, the effect will disappear when the subshell exits.

Comment: This is not really why. The OP is trying to use a pipe to construct an argument string; this never works, it's not specific to `cd`.